# Transformar o retorno HttpResponseMessage em JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Minha API atualmente retorna os valores do banco em JSON.

Caso nenhum valor seja encontrado, eu retorno um `HttpResponseMessage` com o código de erro 404.

Porém, ao testar a requisição, apenas a mensagem contida em `Content` é apresentada.

Gostaria de retornar todos os valores preenchidos (`Content`, `StatusCode` e `ReasonPhrase`) no estilo JSON (chave-valor).

Isso é possível?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("user/")]
public List<user> Get()
{
    new UserController();
    IQueryable<user> users = from itens in db.user select itens;
    if (!users.Any())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage error = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Nenhum usuário encontrado")),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            ReasonPhrase = "User Not Found"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(error);
        }
        return users.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: `StatusCode` e `ReasonPhrase` fazem parte do cabeçalho da resposta. Se você quer que isto faça parte do corpo vai ter que concatenar os valores em `Content` ou então personalizar a resposta.

Comment: @LINQ obrigado pela resposta. Vi que é possível através de sua resposta, porém minha pouca experiência me diz que talvez não seja a melhor forma. Como é feito essa tratativa em produção?

Comment: Nunca fiz uso dos valores do cabeçalho num JSON, até porque sempre é possível recuperar estes valores no lado do cliente. Não seria melhor apenas mudar a regra na aplicação cliente?

Comment: Ainda não implementamos o recebimento dos dados no cliente. O teste foi realizado via postman. Acredito que com esse conteúdo eu consiga seguir. Obrigado pelas informações. Poderia editar o comentário como resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatusCode` e `ReasonPhrase` fazem parte do cabeçalho da resposta. Se você quer que isto faça parte do corpo vai ter que concatenar os valores em `Content` ou então personalizar a resposta.

Talvez você devesse repensar um pouco essa necessidade, uma vez que o cabeçalho da resposta sempre vai estar disponível para o cliente (a aplicação que consome a API) acessar.